# How can I get the current directory name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the current directory of the file in Javascript so I can use that to trigger a different jquery function for each section of my site.

```
if (current_directory) = "example" {
var activeicon = ".icon_one span";
};
elseif (current_directory) = "example2" {
var activeicon = ".icon_two span";
};
else {
var activeicon = ".icon_default span";
};

$(activeicon).show();
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 102):

window.location.pathname will get you the directory, as well as the page name. You could then use .substring() to get the directory:

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: my joomla site produces url's like this:

http://localhost/sub/sub/sub/index.php/ali-mm-d#tab2 (among other strange things)

thus this approach produces NOT a directory, but rather:
http://localhost/sub/sub/sub/index.php

Comment: FYI: if `loc === '/'` then `dir === ''`

Answer (score 62):

In Node.js, you could use:

```
console.log('Current directory: ' + process.cwd());
```

Comment: Please describe more.

Comment: this answer for nodejs platform.
you should tell where you run javascript, before answer on this question.

Comment: For eg. in the main server.js file as constant in any case ...

Answer (score 23):

You can use `window.location.pathname.split('/');`

That will produce an array with all of the items between the /'s

Answer (score 19):

**complete URL**

If you want the complete URL e.g. `http://website/basedirectory/workingdirectory/` use:

```
var location = window.location.href;
var directoryPath = location.substring(0, location.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

**local path**

If you want the local path without domain e.g. `/basedirectory/workingdirectory/` use:

```
var location = window.location.pathname;
var directoryPath = location.substring(0, location.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

In case you don't need the slash at the end, remove the `+1` after `location.lastIndexOf("/")+1`.

**directory name**

If you only want the current directory name, where the script is running in, e.g. `workingdirectory` use:

```
var location = window.location.pathname;
var path = location.substring(0, location.lastIndexOf("/"));
var directoryName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: location causes Google Chrome to reload the page, change the variable name to something else like location1

Comment: Saved me big time with this! Thank you

Comment: You're my angel for today!

Answer (score 16):

This will work for actual paths on the file system if you're not talking the URL string.

```
var path = document.location.pathname;
var directory = path.substring(path.indexOf('/'), path.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: var path = document.location.pathname;

var dir = path.substring(path.indexOf('/'), path.lastIndexOf('/'));

Answer (score 10):

For both / and \:

```
window.location.pathname.replace(/[^\\\/]*$/, '');
```

To return without the trailing slash, do:

```
window.location.pathname.replace(/[\\\/][^\\\/]*$/, '');
```

Comment: This works in IE<9, while the answers using .lastIndexOf do not.  +1 for this reason.

Answer (score 8):

This one-liner works:

```
var currentDirectory = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')
```

Comment: Trying to remove my down vote but SO won't let me because I voted on this recently. that makes a lot of sense...

Answer (score 4):

An interesting approach to get the `dirname` of the current URL is to make use of your browser's built-in path resolution. You can do that by:

1. Create a link to `.`, i.e. the current directory
2. Use the [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) interface of the link to get the resolved URL or path equivalent to `.`.

Here's one line of code that does just that:

```
Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {href: '.'}).pathname
```

In contrast to some of the other solutions presented here, the result of this method will always have a trailing slash. E.g. running it on this page will yield `/questions/3151436/`, running it on `https://stackoverflow.com/` will yield `/`.

It's also easy to get the full URL instead of the path. Just read the `href` property instead of `pathname`.

Finally, this approach should work in even the most ancient browsers if you don't use `Object.assign`:

```
function getCurrentDir () {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '.';
    return link.pathname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location).pathname

Answer (score 1):

If you want the complete URL e.g. `website.com/workingdirectory/` use:
`window.location.hostname+window.location.pathname.replace(/[^\\\/]*$/, '');`

Answer (score 0):

I find this way pretty reliable to find the url of current page, by using the standard [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL). Fits well to create new URLs, using relative and absolute paths

```js
url = window.location
console.log(url);
//strip pagename from pathname
currentdir = new URL(url.pathname.replace( /[^\/]*$/, ''), url.origin);
//now make new paths relative to currentdir
console.log(new URL("/dir1/dir2/hello.html", currentdir));
console.log(new URL("../../dir1/dir2/hello.html", currentdir));
console.log(new URL("../dir1/dir2/hello.html", currentdir));
console.log(new URL("./dir1/dir2/hello.html", currentdir));
console.log(new URL("dir1/dir2/hello.html", currentdir));
currentdir.port = 1234;
console.log(new URL("dir1/dir2/hello.html", currentdir));
```

There are current outputs expected, supposing the current page is
`https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/pages/js/string-replace.html`

```
https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/pages/js/string-replace.html
"currentdir = https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/pages/js/"
https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/dir1/dir2/hello.html
https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/dir1/dir2/hello.html
https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/pages/dir1/dir2/hello.html
https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/pages/js/dir1/dir2/hello.html
https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/pages/js/dir1/dir2/hello.html
https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net:1234/pages/js/dir1/dir2/hello.html
```

Answer (score 0):

In Deno, you can use [`Deno.cwd()`](https://deno.land/api@v1.31.3?s=Deno.cwd):

```js
const currentWorkingDirectory = Deno.cwd();
console.log(currentWorkingDirectory);
```

In Node.js, you can use [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processcwd):

```js
const currentWorkingDirectory = process.cwd();
console.log(currentWorkingDirectory);
```

In browser client code, you can use [`location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/pathname):

```js
const pathname = location.pathname;
console.log(pathname);

//Beware that the pathname might not correspond to a file
//The `|| 1` handles the case when pathname is just "/", making it return "/"
const assumedDirectory = pathname.substring(0, (pathname.lastIndexOf("/") || 1));
console.log(assumedDirectory);
```

---

P.S.:

To make your code work both in Deno & Node.js, you could do something like:

```js
function cwd() {
  try {
    return process.cwd();
  }
  catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof ReferenceError) {
      return Deno.cwd();
    }
    else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

// Or otherwise just:
((typeof process === "object") ? process : Deno).cwd();
```