# check pathname to load different code

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to check pathname to see which html version is loaded to check the language(English, French...)

My pathname for English language is :

```
"/C:/Users/user/workspace/webapp-sandbox/target/classes/$%7Benv.WEBROOT%7D/sendbox/en/fb-result.html"
```

My pathname for French language is :

```
"/C:/Users/user/workspace/webapp-sandbox/target/classes/$%7Benv.WEBROOT%7D/sendbox/fr/fb-result.html"
```

I don't know exactly how can I check the current URL. Should I use `window.location.search` method in order to look for the locale (`en` or `fr`)?

Comment: Maybe window.location and [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: You also could try to get the current directory name in Javascript like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151436/how-can-i-get-the-current-directory-name-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ( using Split command) ( p.s. your path is incorrect .... `/c:/users....`)

`"/C:/Users/user/workspace/webapp-sandbox/target/classes/$%7Benv.WEBROOT%7D/sendbox/en/fb-result.html".split('/')[10]`

result :

```
"en"
```

while

```
"/C:/Users/user/workspace/webapp-sandbox/target/classes/$%7Benv.WEBROOT%7D/sendbox/fr/fb-result.html".split('/')[10]"
```

result :

```
"fr"
```

Answer (score 0):

location.search is what comes after ?. You can do

```
var fr = location.href.indexOf('/sendbox/fr')!=-1;
var en = location.href.indexOf('/sendbox/en')!=-1;
```