# Make HTML change image name to directory name

Tags: html, css

I have many different directories which are named `SOMECITY-STATE`.

Each of these directories has one and the same `index.html`, with only one difference, the header image is different in every one of them.

Now I have a separate header-image folder in which the images are named all the same like `SOMECITY-STATE.JPG`

What I want to do is, to put some code in html file to make it automatically read the directory name e.g. `NEW-YORK-NY` and make the page display the `../banners/new-york-ny.jpg` as it's header image.

```
<div class="header-image"> <a href="#"><img src="banners/new-york-ny.jpg"></a> </div>
```

Where  `mydomain.com/directory1` should display the image `../banners/directory1.jpg` and `mydomain.com/directory2` should display the image `../banners/directory2.jpg`

Is this possible?

Comment: You can do this client-side with JavaScript, or you can use something server-side (Node.js/Webpack, PHP, etc.) to dynamically generate your pages.

Comment: I don't know how to. I would prefer client-side. How can I do it with javascript?

Comment: Who knows... without seeing your HTML, it's impossible to provide a specific answer.

Comment: <div class="header-image">
<a href="#"><img src="banners/new-york-ny.jpg"></a>
 </div> This is the thing, nothing special.. Now here in the "new-york-ny.jpg" it should say whatever the directory is opened. It's like mysite.com/dir1 or dir2. if it's dir1 the image name should be dir1.jpg

Comment: You can change the src like this:  `document.querySelector('.header-image img').src = 'http://example.com/banners/new-york-ny.jpg');`  However... why not just put the banners in a relative path and always name them the same thing?  `banner.jpg`, in a path relative to the actual page?  That's better than dynamically changing it.

Comment: Where do I put this document.queryselector quote that you gave me? Sorry I'm not familiar with javascript coding.. I only know a little html

Comment: You would put it in a `<script>` tag, but go read up on some basic JavaScript first.

Answer (score 0):

**It is indeed.**

Just before the ending `</body>` tag inside each `index.html` file, include this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var loc = window.location.pathname;
  var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
  $('.header-image img').attr('src', '../banners/' + dir + '.jpg');
</script>
```

**What's happening?**

1. The first line adds the jQuery library to your webpage, which makes what you're trying to do much easier.
2. Next, I put some code inside `<script>` tags, so the browser knows it's going to be Javascript.
3. The first line inside the `<script>` grabs the folder that your `index.html` file is in, but it looks like "/new-york-ny/" right now.
4. The next line takes "/new-york-ny/" and takes off the last slash, so it's just "/new-york-ny".
5. The last line of code selects the image within the `div` with the `header-image` class, and sets its `src` attribute to "/new-york-ny", but also adds "../banners" and ".jpg" to it at the same time, making it "../banners/new-york-ny.jpg", which is hopefully what you want.

(credit to Ryan Kinal on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151436/how-can-i-get-the-current-directory-name-in-javascript) for some of the code)

I hope it helps!