# Get javascript filepath in Windows Script Host

Tags: javascript, windows, directory, path, windows-scripting

When using .js files that are run with Windows Script Host, is it possible to get the path of the .js file that is running (which is not the same as the current working directory)? In other words, I'm wanting something similar to PowerShell's `$PSScriptRoot` variable. Is there any way to get this?

The reason I want this is because the working directory when these scripts are executed is not always the same as the location of the .js file itself, but I want my code to reference things relative to the location of the .js file.

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151436/how-can-i-get-the-current-directory-name-in-javascript/3151474

Comment: @Dexirian, No, this isn't web-based javascript, this is using Windows Script Host.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can get this with Node Js 

    const path = require('path'); // you can install this with npm

    // __dirname = C:\dev\project
    // __filename = C:\dev\project\index.js
    const dir= path.basename(__dirname);
    const archive= path.basename(__filename);
    const fullpath = path.join(dir, archive);

    console.log('Dir:', dir); // Dir: test
    console.log('Archive:', archive); // Archive: index.js
    console.log('Dir + Archive:', fullpath); // Dir + Archive: project\index.js
```

Comment: Is it possible to use node js with Windows Script Host? I'm not sure that it is.