# In the html of vsc, I put the path of my computer image file in the img tag. but doesn't work

Tags: html, image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B56f1.png)
In visual studio code,

I put in same folder img and html file, and

```
<img src="computer path" alt="..."/>
```

but it doesn't work. how should I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3typ.png)

Comment: Get current directory via js and then append your image name. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151436/how-can-i-get-the-current-directory-name-in-javascript/3151479

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="..."/>
```

That should do the trick!

Hope it helped

Comment: <img src="logo_img.png" alt="..."/> still don't work.....

Comment: How are you running that .html file of yours?

Comment: Did u try. <img src="/logo_img.png" alt="..."/>